# How do I change Atom's bottom window height?

Tags: atom-editor, atom-runner

I recently started using Atom and try to make it as nice to work with as possible.
However I couldn't figure out how to change the height of the bottom window (a name for it would already help).
My goal is to have my console etc. as minimalistic as possible.
E.g.:
[Atom's bottom window shown here with an output example from Atom-Runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aubOu.png)

1. How do I only show the atom-runner's output and not the grey rest of the window on top of it?
2. How can I get rid of unnecessary labels like "Atom Runner: data.py"?

I found that you can change quite a bit within the `styles.less` file with commands like:

```
atom-workspace {
  height: calc(...);
}
```

But that didn't really help me.

Comment: Like all browsers, Atom has an inspector you can use to determine an elements class

Comment: @idleberg I tried that one with `cmd+alt+I`, but couldn't find the element class I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However I couldn't figure out how to change the height of the bottom window (a name for it would already help).

`atom-runner` displays its results in a [bottom panel](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.21.1/Panel). There are a few different types of containers in the Atom window:

1. Panes are the content in the middle of the editor. Panes can hold as many items as you want, which are usually associated with a specific file (see `TextEditors`)
2. Docks are the expandable areas just outside the panes (the `tree-view` and `github` packages use docks). They can have multiple items and will create tabs for them.
3. Panels are the spaces on the edge of the Atom window. You can't hide them without disabling the whole package.

> How do I only show the atom-runner's output and not the grey rest of the window on top of it?

The "grey rest of the window" is the bottom dock. You can hide it by clicking on the semicircle with the down arrow.

> How can I get rid of unnecessary labels like "Atom Runner: data.py"?

I disagree that it's unnecessary, and you might some day find that you need to know what file you ran. However, if you want to do this, you can add the following to your `styles.less`:

```
.atom-runner h1 {
  display: none;
}
```